# How to add an attachment to an email via MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have code to send an email from MS Access via Outlook when I click the send button on the form. I set up the email form so depending on the customer I select, I can choose from the drop down which file I want to attach.

I have the documents saved as a hyperlink for each customer.

When I try to choose from the drop down list, it says

> "Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct."

I am not sure why this happens as when I click the link it takes me to the right file.

Could there be another solution?

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click()
    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    oEmail.To = Me.cboEmail
    oEmail.Subject = Me.txtSubject.Value
    oEmail.Body = Me.txtBody.Value
    If Len(Me.cboAttachment) > 0 Then
        oEmail.Attachments.Add Me.cboAttachment.Value
    End If
    With oEmail
        If Not IsNull(.To) And Not IsNull(.Subject) And Not IsNull(.Body) Then
            .Send
            MsgBox "Email Sent!"
        Else
            MsgBox "please fill out the required fields."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're sure the file exists check the value of `Me.cboAttachment.Value` when the code executes.  Does it paste into File Explorer and open the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dir` function to check if the file exist.

```vb
If Len(Me.cboAttachment) > 0 And Dir(Me.cboAttachment.Value) <> "" Then
    oEmail.Attachments.Add Me.cboAttachment.Value
End If
```